# Оптимизация новых инструкций ассмеблера

Tags: ассемблер, оптимизация

Правильно ли я понимаю, что чем новее используемая в программе на ассемблере инструкция, тем хуже оптимизируется компилятором программа, использующая её? Т.е. чем более примитивный и старый набор инструкций для написания программы на ассемблере используется, тем лучше она поддаётся оптимизации и быстрее работает из-за лучше продуманной за прошедшее время оптимизации используемого набора инструкций?

Comment: звучит как какая-то глупость... сложно даже за что-то зацепиться, чтобы сказать, что именно здесь не так...

Comment: Вряд ли тут есть спецы, занимающиеся оптимизацией в компиляторах, но интуитивно кажется, что вы не верно оцениваете инструменты (алгоритмы), которые используются при оптимизации конкретного набора инструкций.

Comment: Нет и нет. С чего вы это взяли?

Comment: Я ничего не брал. А вы?